# How does Laplace expansion work?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, laplace-expansion

> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
>
> Caculate its determinant.

Although it has small numbers, it's still fairly long to calculate the determinant of a large matrix. Peeking at the solution to this exercise, it says

> Applying Laplace expansion on the second row and then on the third, we
>   obtain a matrix of size $3$ where we can apply Sarrus. The determinant
>   is $1 - a$.

I don't really know either of those terms, *Laplace* and *Sarrus*. Looking up at Wikipedia, Sarrus is pretty clear to me now, but Laplace is still fairly confusing.

How does Laplace expansion work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Expand along the rows that have the **most** zeros.

Expanding along row 2, we have:

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Note, what I mean by expanding along row $2$ using Laplace Expansion (see link below), is:

$$0 \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0  & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} + 1 \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1  & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} + 0 \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1  & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} + 0 \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1  & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} + 0 \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1  & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Notice **all** of the zero terms that are leading? Only one item with a $1$ in front survives. Repeating this process two more times yields the result as follows.

Expanding along row 3, we have:

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1  & 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Expanding along row 2, we have:

$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a\\ 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Result:

$$\mbox{det} ~ = ~ (1-a)$$

I am basically using [*Laplace Expansion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion), because all the leading numbers for the expansion are zero. The site includes an example of where this is not the case.

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of expanding? I believe I have mixed the concepts.

Comment: Just a doubt: In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion, at the first example, they seem to alternate the signs (+, -, +). The same occurs with the second example (-, +, -). What determines the sign?

Comment: Why does the second example begin with $-$ rather than $+$? Because it's the second column? If I choose the, dunno, fourth column, it would also begin with $-$?

Comment: I should be more clear, it is $(-1)^{i + j}$, so the term they are starting with is $a_{2,1}$, hence $(-1)^{i + j} = (-1)^3 = -1$. Clear?

Comment: Thank you, I can do Laplace now. I think.

Comment: Did, it does :D